# Z-order of image view: place higher than listview, but lower than listview item's children

Tags: android, android-layout, z-order

We have:

ImageView - A,

ListView - B,

1 of listview items - C,

1 of C's children - D,

z(x) - z-order of a view.

My question - is it possible to make my views render in accordance with this rule:

```
z(B) < z(A) < z(D)
```

?

In other words, I want imageview to be rendered in front of listview, but behind listview items' children. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. The children of the ListView will live in the ListView and are always at the same Z position as the ListView itself.

What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you can give us an example view or describe the effect that you want to have a little bit more and we can provide you with an alternative solution for your layout.